# Is it safe to build windows in Grounded?

Tags: grounded

I'm fairly new on Grounded: I've never ventured past the oak tree, and I'm only wearing clover/acorn armor. So, encounters with nearly every aggressive creature result in me fleeing in terror... if I'm lucky enough to flee.

I'm building my first decent-ish base, and I want it to be completely secure. **Is it safe to place windows, or will enemy mobs be able to pass through them?** I've read on [this wiki](https://grounded.fandom.com/wiki/Windowed_Grass_Wall) that:

> Some Creatures that are small enough (such as Gnats) can fly through the windows and into the interior of the players base.

Are mobs also able to *crawl* through windows, or is it limited to flying creatures? I don't care about gnats (and there aren't any hostile flying creatures around my area), but I do care about ants, or larvae, or even those pesky lawn mites... which surely are small enough for a window.

Comment: It's been a while since I last played through grounded. Not sure what has changed since then. But in my time playing it (within the first 6 months of its release to early access), all creatures would easily get into my bases, despite being completely surrounded by walls. Ants would just spawn inside or something (walls still fully intact but they're in my base). Might have been my base location (the first point of interest in the game) so that might be a factor. That and they would constantly eat through my chests, even when above ground and behind walls.

Comment: @JeffMercado Oof! They must have fixed that, I've been playing a few hours today and it didn't happen. Thanks goodness, most creatures are already terrifying enough when they are outside my house! Which by the way, I believe it's located exactly at the same place yours was.